# Possiblity to use both SpringBoot graphql and Spring boot web starter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-graphql

I am building a multi module maven project.
In one module I have my SpringBoot application
And in another module, I have the SpringBoot Graphql controllers.

However, it seems that SpringBoot does not start the GraphQL server.

Did anyone of you already have this issue?

PS: Yes I used @ComponentScan to tell SpringBoot to scan my second Maven module for Graphql.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan({"com.beauregard.pierre.demo", "com.beauregard.pierre.graphql"})
public class RestRootApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RestRootApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

THank you for your help.

Comment: Could you run your application with the `--debug` flag and share here the condition evaluation report for the GraphQL auto-configurations? See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.spring-application.startup-failure